# Sql запрос поиска в дереве

Tags: mysql, sql

Нужно составить **sql запрос**, с помощью которого можно узнать входит ли пользователь в ветку партнёров.

**Поясняю:** допустим есть пользователь A, у которого есть партнёры B, C, D, - у этих партнёров свои партнёры и так далее. В итоге получается дерево.

**К примеру:** есть такая ветка партнёров: `A -> C -> F -> H -> P`, нужно узнать входит ли пользователь H в ветку где один из предшественников - пользователь C.

Максимальный уровень вхождения для поиска в ветке = 10, но, возможно будет больше или меньше.

[image: визуальное представление таблицы партнёров]

Описание полей таблицы:

- `id` - ID записи партнёра
- `user_id` - ID пользователя
- `partner_id` - ID партнёра пользователя

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `partners` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `partner_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `partners_user_id_partner_id_unique` (`user_id`,`partner_id`),
  KEY `partners_user_id_partner_id_index` (`user_id`,`partner_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

*P.S. Mysql v5.5*

Comment: Я правильно понял, что партнера нужно смотреть только по дереву вверх?

Comment: @etki Да, всё верно поняли.

Comment: На текущей схеме хранения одним запросом не обойтись. Вернее, с учётом ограниченной максимальной вложенности, можно, но это будет монстр, к тому же крайне медлительный и прожорливый. Можно изменить схему хранения (перейти на любую, ориентированную на хранение дерева), либо написать пользовательскую функцию, которая выполняет требуемую проверку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На этот случай можно хранить иерархию в строке, как вы и написали, через разделитель, для каждого пользователя. В этом случае, определив ветку партнёра, вы сможете составить RLIKE или LIKE выражение на вхождение строкового значения из корневой ветки. Это называется материализованное значение пути ([МТЗ](https://bojanz.wordpress.com/2014/04/25/storing-hierarchical-data-materialized-path/)), и вот его пример из ссылки:

```
ID | NAME                     | PATH
100 | Electronics & Computers | /100
101 | Games                   | /100/101
102 | Xbox360                 | /100/101/102
103 | PS4                     | /100/101/103
```

Запросы к таблице будут выглядеть так:

```
-- Найти детей игрушек (Games):
SELECT * FROM catalog WHERE path LIKE “/100/101/%”
-- Изменить родителя:
UPDATE catalog SET path = REPLACE(path, ‘/100/101’, ‘/200/201’) WHERE path LIKE ‘/100/101/%’
```